# Windows 8 style font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, windows

How do I get the Windows 8 font styling in LaTeX(the package)? A sample font is:[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This font is called [Segoe UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx). Various weights are used at different sizes; see the Microsoft page I linked to for details.

To use this font in LaTeX, compile your document with XeLaTeX or LuaTeX, and load the fonts with the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.